# Filter Not Accepting Date Variable

Tags: vba, excel

trying my hand at some vba that I have copied and cahnged.

This works well

```
With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>2014-12-02"
        rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```

I have created a variable called factorydate

```
factorydate = Worksheets("systemdata").Cells(3, "C").Value
```

How do I replace the date '2014-12-02' with the variable factorydate? something like:

```
With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & factorydate
        rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```

Comment: Try: `& DateValue(factorydate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value in `.Cells(3, "C").Value` is a date (or you `Dim factorydate as Date`) then the order will change of the numbers because of date default ordering.  IF IT IS A DATE VALUE, I would try:

```
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & year(factorydate) & "-" & month(factorydate) & "-" & day(factorydate)
```

to make sure it puts your syntax in correctly

EDIT: or do this:

```
factorydate = Format(factorydate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & factorydate
```

2EDIT: final option:

```
factorydate = Worksheets("systemdata").Cells(3, "C").Text
```

using `.Text` returns the exact text string to ensure your filter applies correctly.

Comment: Thanks Chris, spot on!